# Create generic class for java program

Tags: java, swing, generics

I have written a class in Java for JTextField Focus Listener and I don't know how to write this class as generic class. Once I wrote the generic class it should be used by all the JTextFields how can I do this please tell me the way through coding. How to write a generic class for this following code:

```
package javaapplication7;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class testfocuss{
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    JTextField component = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField component1 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField component2 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField component3 = new JTextField(20);
    component.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener());
    component1.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener());
     component2.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener());
      component3.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener());
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.layout(new FlowLayout());
    f.add(component1);
    f.add(component);
     f.add(component2);
      f.add(component3);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

  }
}
class MyFocusListener extends FocusAdapter {
  //boolean showingDialog = false;

  public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
    final JTextComponent c = (JTextComponent) evt.getSource();
    String s = c.getText();
    c.requestFocus();
    c.selectAll();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
    c.setSelectionStart(i);
        c.setSelectionEnd(i);
        break;
    }
    }
  }

  public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
    final JTextComponent c = (JTextComponent) evt.getSource();
    String s = c.getText();

   if (evt.isTemporary()) {
     return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
     if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        //System.out.println("must only contain digits");
        c.requestFocus();
        c.selectAll();
        break;
      }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to make generic? Your focus listener already works for all `JTextComponents`.

Comment: That works properly.how to write focuslistener as a generic class?and how to use that generic class in some other program that has JTextField.

Comment: +1, No need for generics there. An instanceof before casting would be a good thing.

Comment: But i create generic class and then  I use that generic class to use an another program.how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    package javaapplication7;

    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

    public class testfocuss {
        public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

            JTextField component = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField component1 = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField component2 = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField component3 = new JTextField(20);
            MyFocusListener l = new MyFocusListener();
            component.addFocusListener(l);
            component1.addFocusListener(l);
            component2.addFocusListener(l);
            component3.addFocusListener(l);
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            f.add(component1);
            f.add(component);
            f.add(component2);
            f.add(component3);
            f.pack();
            f.setVisible(true);

        }
    }

    class MyFocusListener<C extends JTextComponent> extends FocusAdapter {
        // boolean showingDialog = false;

        public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
            final C c = (C) evt.getSource();
            String s = c.getText();
            c.requestFocus();
            c.selectAll();

            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                    c.setSelectionStart(i);
                    c.setSelectionEnd(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
            final C c = (C) evt.getSource();
            String s = c.getText();

            if (evt.isTemporary()) {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                    // System.out.println("must only contain digits");
                    c.requestFocus();
                    c.selectAll();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Notice: Your listener is cappable to use multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code needs any generics; `MyFocusListener` already works for all `JTextComponents`, not only `JTextFields`, and it shouldn't work for any other classes as it uses methods declared in `JTextComponent`. You can already use it in other applications.

If you still want to make the listener use generics (homework?), use this:

```
class MyFocusListener<T extends JTextComponent> extends FocusAdapter {

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
        final T c = (T)evt.getSource();
        String s = c.getText();
        c.requestFocus();
        c.selectAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                c.setSelectionStart(i);
                c.setSelectionEnd(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
        final T c = (T) evt.getSource();
        String s = c.getText();

        if (evt.isTemporary()) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            c.requestFocus();
                c.selectAll();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```